# Is there an etymological connection between "comitia" and "comes"?

Tags: etymology, history, derivation

In the Roman Republic, the word *comitia* was used for the various popular assemblies (e.g. *comitia centuriata*). I can't find any clear indication online as to its etymological roots.

I was wondering whether it could be derived from the word *comes*, meaning companion or comrade. Its derivation could be analogous to that of *militia* from *miles*. Does this make sense linguistically? And is there some possible evidence out there that could be used for or against this theory?

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for an excellent first question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Comitia* is indeed derived from *comes*. Both come from the prefix *com-* "with, together" plus the root *i-* "go": a companion is someone who goes with you, and an assembly is a place where people go together.

Here's the entry from de Vaan's etymological dictionary of Latin:

[image]